# Meaning of 1-digit base 100 number in RSA Cryptosystem

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

> > Explani the RSA cryptosystem by showing coding and decoding of the word **Birthday** if the public key is known to be $(101, 3)$. Consider each alphabet as 1-digit base 100-number.

I know how to code it. Only I want to ask what is the meaning of $\textbf{ Consider each alphabet as 1-digit base 100-number}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a standard terminology. I suspect the author actually missed some words and meant "consider each *letter of the* alphabet ..." though that's still far from a standard way to phrase things.

My best guess is that they're encoding each letter as a number between 0 and 100, probably with the scheme

```
A - 1
B - 2
C - 3
D - 4
....
```

and then encrypting each letter separately.

(This is a rather bad way of using RSA -- in addition to the brute-forcing opportunity inherent in only having 26 different messages, there's the fact that the number 1 always encrypts to itself. Check if your source material defines a concrete coding somewhere else).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.If we replace 100 by 10, then what change we will see in these alphabets.

Comment: @Struggler: I'm not sure I understand that question. What do you imagine  happens to your public key if you "replace 100 by 10"? It wouldn't do to make it $(11,3)$, because $11$ is not a product of two primes.